# Configuring Tealeaf With worklight

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, tealeaf

We have installed tealeaf server with all components like PCA server.we would like to know how to give the connectivity from mobile native app/ from worklight to tealeaf server. How to install or how to configure or how to capture the data from mobile to tealeaf.

1. File Name - TLFConfigurableItems.plist
2. Property Name - PostMessageUrl.
   If someone help us how to solve this issue.

Comment: Why not mention your worklight version?

Answer (score 0):

Please note that Tealeaf is an unsupported integration in MobileFirst Platform Foundation 7.1 and MobileFirst Foundation 8.0, if you are using an earlier release than those but intend on upgrading, you should consider your integration and why it is Tealeaf that you require of all possible solutions.

Comment: i will agree with you...but client need lesser version 6.3 to 7.0. Is it possible   to screen capture worklight to tealeaf server. How to give the connectivity or configure.Thanks for your immediate response.

Comment: PostMessageUrl  in this property we need to pointout the server from device to tealeaf server (CX , PCA). which one to be used and how to configure. please share the document.